# EAGLE Modules with Layout

Tags: eaglecad

I made a module with EAGLE's 'module' feature.
Layout of multiple instances will be almost the same so is there a way to assign a layout to the module so that I don't have to do the layout for each module manually?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no feature for this.

There are a few workarounds involving disconnecting the schematic <-> board connection.

## Make sure you have a backup

https://www.element14.com/community/thread/13846/l/block-copy-in-eagle-pcb-layout

> Sometimes circuit boards will have duplicate sections of schematic
>   that you want to layout identically.  You could do this by laying out
>   each section separately, but for large or complex layouts this would
>   be very time consuming.  Eagle does not have a function that allows
>   you to directly duplicate your layouts, so you have to use this
>   workaround:
>
> 1. Create the schematic for the section you want to duplicate.  You can have additional schematic done at that time too if you like.
> 2. Create the layout for that section.  You can have additional layout done at that time if you like.
> 3. Close the layout so that you only have the schematic open.
> 4. Use the window selection tool to surround the section of schematic you want to duplicate in the layout.
> 5. Use the scissors tool to copy the selection to the buffer.
> 6. Use the dropdown EDIT: PASTE to finish the copy operation.
> 7. Save the schematic and close it.
> 8. Open the layout. Click OK to acknowledge the warning about the schematic and board not being consistent. Close the schematic that
>      opened when you opened the layout so that you only have the layout
>      open.
> 9. Do the same window select, scissors, paste operation on the layout.  YOU MUST COPY EXACTLY THE SAME ITEMS AS YOU DID IN THE SCHEMATIC. 
>      THIS INCLUDES COMPONENTS AND NETS.
> 10. Save the layout and open the schematic.  You should have both the schematic and layout open at this point.
> 11. In the layout, run ERC and you'll get a long list of nets that don't match.  Don't worry: you only have to fix each net once.  This
>       is usually only 5 or 6 nets to fix the whole list.
> 12. The original section of layout will have nets named GND.  The new section will have them named GND1.  The original section of the
>       schematic will have the nets named GND.  The new section will also
>       have them named GND.  The task here is to rename the net GND1 to GND
>       in the layout.
> 13. Type "show GND1" in the command line.  This will highlight GND1.
> 14. Use the name tool (R2 Icon) to change the name GND1 to GND.  If prompted, the rename applies to all nets.
> 15. If you run ERC again, you'll find that all of the GND/GND1 errors are gone.  Redo this renaming process a few more times for the
>       remaining name1 nets and you're done.
>
> Additional note: If you don't
>   have any airwires for the net you're trying to rename then you'll have
>   to create one using the line tool and the name tool: Create a line. 
>   Rename that line using the R2 tool to the net name you need to rename
>   (e.g. GND1).  This will connect the line to the pad that was
>   previously un-airwired.  Now you can rename the airwire or line to the
>   right name (e.g. GND) to fix that net.

Comment: I will look into this. It is also not avaliable in version 8 I presume. Instead of adding features of actual value EAGLE devs just added some fancy UI staff, apparently.

Comment: @Aenid Eagle was bought by Autodesk, expect no enhancements until they rename it.